# basis of tangent space as kernel of differential form

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-forms, tangent-spaces

Let $\alpha = 8dx - 4dy + 2dz$. Find a basis for the kernel of $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Here I am trying to say that the kernel of $\alpha$ will generate a tangent space for $\alpha = 2xdx-2ydy+2zdz-2wdw$ at $(4,2,1,0)$ on the hypersurface  $x^2-y^2+z^2-w^2=1$.

For example, take $\omega=2dx$. Then $\ker\omega= \rm{span}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}, \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\right)$ since applying $2dx$ to these vectors gives $0$. I cannot figure out how to use the same reasoning for $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can just use the definition of kernel. A vector in $\mathbb R^4$ is a combination $X = a\partial_x + b \partial_y + c\partial_z + d\partial_w$. Then $X$ sits in the kernel of $\alpha$ if $\alpha(X) = 0$, which gives
$$8a-4b+2c=0, \quad d \in \mathbb R.$$
Therefore $c=2b-4a$ and $X=a\partial_x + b\partial_y + (2b-4a)\partial_z+d\partial_w$. So the kernel of $\alpha$ is given by the span of $\partial_x - 4\partial_z, \partial_y + 2\partial_z, \partial_w$, and is thus three-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you. I had never seen this before but it certainly gives me a better picture.

Comment: This is not totally clear to me, but it looks like you just need to replace $(x,y,z,w)=(4,2,1,0)$ into the matrix...